# isAnnotationPresent() return false when used with super type reference in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, supertype

I m trying to get the annotation details from super type reference variable using reflection, to make the method accept all sub types. But `isAnnotationPresent()` returning `false`. Same with other annotation related methods. If used on the exact type, output is as expected.

I know that annotation info will be available on the Object even I m referring through super type.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Table {
    String name();
}
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeEntity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SomeEntity.class.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); // true
        System.out.println(new SomeEntity().getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); // true

        Class<?> o1 = SomeEntity.class;
        System.out.println(o1.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); // false

        Class<SomeEntity> o2 = SomeEntity.class;
        System.out.println(o2.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); // false

        Object o3 = SomeEntity.class;
        System.out.println(o3.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); // false
    }
}
```

How to get the annotation info?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're calling `getClass()` *on* a `Class<?>`, which will give `Class<Class>`. Now `Class` itself *isn't* annotated, which is why you're getting false. I think you want:

```
// Note no call to o1.getClass()
Class<?> o1 = SomeEntity.class;
System.out.println(o1.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class));
```

Comment: Oh my! How could I miss that :( I m changing some code repeatedly and missed to remove the `getClass()` after changing the method parameter from `Object` to `Class`. I knew my question is so dumb as I've done similar thing thousand times. Thanks for spotting my ignorance.

Comment: @mrCoder typical "abuse of copy-paste" issue... Everyone falls into this one :)

Comment: @Romain Yeah, quite some time we can't help with that. ha ha

Comment: But to get the annotation info when referring using `Object`? Is it possible? the last case in my OP. Thanks

Comment: @mrCoder It'll work if you set `o3` to an instance of `SomeEntity`, and then call `getClass().isAnnotationPresent(...)` on it. But as you write it, it simply cannot work (at least not in a way that static typing easily allows).

Comment: @mrCoder: You'd have to cast to `Class<?>`: `Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) o3;` - but if you've got a class reference, why have you only got it as `Object` to start with?

Comment: Previous code accepts `Object` and at that time `getClass()` is used. Later I've changed to `Class`, but missed to remove the `getClass()`

Comment: To show you the previous code, `void some(Object o) { System.out.println(o.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)); }` and calling the method like `some(SomeEntity.class);`. It was written like that to support all types (objects, classes, ...)

Comment: @mrCoder: Can you change it to `some(AnnotatedElement o)` instead? Then just use `System.out.println(o.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class));`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. But my initial guess is that even if that worked, it'll not accept objects. Now method takes `Class` type and I removed extra `getClass()`, and it is working fine

Comment: @mrCoder: What objects would you want it to accept *other* than AnnotatedElement values, and what would you expect it to do with them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3902/discussion-between-mrcoder-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @mrCoder: No, I'm afraid I don't do chat - it doesn't work well with my usage pattern.

Comment: No problem, I just clicked 'automatically move this discussion to chat' link out of curiosity (first time!). I m using `Class` as parameter

Answer (score 3):

First, see [`java.lang.annotation.Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

Second, as others pointed out, your code is a bit different from your question.

Third, to answer your question..

I have encountered a similar need many times so I have written a short AnnotationUtil class to do this and some other similar things. Spring framework offers a similar AnnotationUtils class and I suppose dozen other packages today also contain pretty much this piece of code so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Anyway this may help you.

```
public static <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<?> clazz, Class<T> annotationType) {
    T result = clazz.getAnnotation(annotationType);
    if (result == null) {
        Class<?> superclass = clazz.getSuperclass();
        if (superclass != null) {
            return getAnnotation(superclass, annotationType);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I m using similar method. But this will not help in my case as I m calling `getClass()` again on the `Class` parameter. Thanks for the `java.lang.annotation.Inherited` tip.

Answer (score 2):

The `o1.getClass()` will give you object of type `java.lang.Class`, which doesn't have `@Table` annotation. I suppose you wanted `o1.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `o1`, `o2` and `o3` are already the `Class<?>` objects on which you'll want to call `isAnnotationPresent(Class<?>)`, you shouldn't call `getClass()` on them before, because at this stage, you'll call `isAnnotationPresent(Class<?>)`on the `Class` class itself, and not on your `SomeEntity` class...